# how to iterate over array[string] in spark scala?

Tags: scala, dictionary, split, flatmap

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oU5iS.png)here is my sample input:

```
val list=List("a;bc:de;f","uvw:xy;z","123:456")
```

I am applying following operation

`val upper=list.map(x=>x.split(":")).map(x=>x.split(";"))`

but it is throwing error-
*error: value split is not a member of Array[String]*

can anyone help how to use both split so that i can get answer!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `list.map(x=>x.split(":"))` will give you a list of Array. Then you are trying to run `.map` an for each item split on an array. I think you want `val upper=list.map(x=>x.split(":").map(x=>x.split(";")))`

Comment: i have to iterate val upper=list.map(x=>x.split(":")).map(x=>x.split(";"))<- from last bracket then how can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code i have tried and it worked:

```
val upper=list.map(x=>x.split(":")).map(x=>x.map(x=>x.split(";")))
```

which gives the output:

```
upper: List[Array[Array[String]]] = List(Array(Array(a, bc), Array(de, f)), Array(Array(uvw), Array(xy, z)), Array(Array(123), Array(456)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `list.map(x=>x.split(":"))` will give you a list of Array.

```
upper: List[Array[String]] = List(Array(a;bc, de;f), Array(uvw, xy;z), Array(123, 456))
```

Mapping afterwards, you can see that the item will be an array where you are trying to run split on.

You might use`flatMap` instead which will first give you `List(a;bc, de;f, uvw, xy;z, 123, 456)` and then you can use map on those items splitting on `;`

```
val upper = list.flatMap(_.split(":")).map(_.split(";"))
```

Output

```
upper: List[Array[String]] = List(Array(a, bc), Array(de, f), Array(uvw), Array(xy, z), Array(123), Array(456))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split` with multiple delimiters in one map iteration :

```
val upper = list.map(x => x.split("[:;]"))

//upper: List[Array[String]] = List(Array(a, bc, de, f), Array(uvw, xy, z), Array(123, 456))
```